# Object Oriented Programming with User Input

Tags: java, eclipse, oop

I have my program working and I have the correct output *ONLY* if I enter one of the correct integer values. I am uncertain how to fix it as if I put in another value I will simply get "Invalid Input" (which I placed in my code), but the month will still be the incorrectly entered integer. I need to know how to fix this issue in my program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class whichMonth {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the month name or number: ");
        int monthNumber = input.nextInt();


        // set up variable access to the class
        AnyMonth inputMonthNumber = new AnyMonth();

        // set the month number from user input
        inputMonthNumber.setMonthnum(monthNumber);

        // get the month name from user input number
        String monthName = inputMonthNumber.getMonthName(monthNumber);

        // print out the month number and month name
        System.out.println("The month number is: " + inputMonthNumber.getMonthnum(monthNumber)
                + "\nThe month name is: " + inputMonthNumber.getMonthName(monthNumber));
    }
}

class AnyMonth {

   int Monthnum;
   String monthName;

   public AnyMonth() {

      Monthnum = 1;
   }
   public AnyMonth(int currentMonthNumber) {

      Monthnum = currentMonthNumber;

      switch(currentMonthNumber) {
         case 1:
            Monthnum = 1;
            monthName = "January";
            System.out.println("January");
            break;
         case 2:
            Monthnum = 2;
            monthName = "February";
            System.out.println("February");
            break;
         case 3:
            Monthnum = 3;
            monthName = "March";
            System.out.println("March");
            break;
         case 4:
            Monthnum = 4;
            monthName = "April";
            System.out.println("April");
            break;
         case 5:
            Monthnum = 5;
            monthName = "May";
            System.out.println("May");
            break;
         case 6:
            Monthnum = 6;
            monthName = "June";
            System.out.println("June");
            break;         
         case 7:
            Monthnum = 7;
            monthName = "July";
            System.out.println("July");
            break;         
         case 8:
            Monthnum = 8;
            monthName = "August";
            System.out.println("August");
            break;         
         case 9:
            Monthnum = 9;
            monthName = "September";
            System.out.println("September");
            break;         
         case 10:
            Monthnum = 10;
            monthName = "October";
            System.out.println("October");
            break;
         case 11:
            Monthnum = 11;
            monthName = "November";
            System.out.println("November");
            break;
         case 12:
            Monthnum = 12;
            monthName = "December";
            System.out.println("December");
            break;
         default:
            Monthnum = 1;
            monthName = "January";
      } 

   } 

   public AnyMonth(String userMonthName) {

      switch(userMonthName) {
         case "January":
            Monthnum = 1;
            monthName = "January";
            System.out.println("January");
            break;
         case "February":
            Monthnum = 2;
            monthName = "February";
            System.out.println("February");
            break;
         case "March":
            Monthnum = 3;
            monthName = "March";
            System.out.println("March");
            break;
         case "April":
            Monthnum = 4;
            monthName = "April";
            System.out.println("April");
            break;
         case "May":
            Monthnum = 5;
            monthName = "May";
            System.out.println("May");
            break;
         case "June":
            Monthnum = 6;
            monthName = "June";
            System.out.println("June");
            break;         
         case "July":
            Monthnum = 7;
            monthName = "July";
            System.out.println("July");
            break;         
         case "August":
            Monthnum = 8;
            monthName = "August";
            System.out.println("August");
            break;         
         case "September":
            Monthnum = 9;
            monthName = "September";
            System.out.println("September");
            break;         
         case "October":
            Monthnum = 10;
            monthName = "October";
            System.out.println("October");
            break;
         case "November":
            Monthnum = 11;
            monthName = "November";
            System.out.println("November");
            break;
         case "December":
            Monthnum = 12;
            monthName = "December";
            System.out.println("December");
            break;
         default:
            Monthnum = 1;
            monthName = "January";

      }    

   }

   public void setMonthnum (int userMonth) {

      Monthnum = userMonth;

      if (userMonth < 1 || userMonth > 12){
         System.out.println("Invalid input");
         this.Monthnum = userMonth;
      } 

   }

   public int getMonthnum(int currentMonthNumber) {

      Monthnum = currentMonthNumber;

      return currentMonthNumber;

   }

   public String getMonthName(int currentMonthName) {

      Monthnum = currentMonthName;
        // use swtich-case here instead, default case should return 1/Jan
      switch(currentMonthName) {
         case 1:
            monthName = "January";
            break;
         case 2:
            monthName = "February";;
            break;
         case 3:
            monthName = "March";
            break;
         case 4:
            monthName = "April";
            break;
         case 5:
            monthName = "May";
            break;
         case 6:
            monthName = "June";
            break;         
         case 7:
            monthName = "July";
            break;         
         case 8:
            monthName = "August";
            break;         
         case 9:
            monthName = "September";
            break;         
         case 10:
            monthName = "October";
            break;
         case 11:
            monthName = "November";
            break;
         case 12:
            monthName = "December";
            break;
         default:
            monthName = "January";

      }
      return monthName;
    }

    public String toString(String monthNameToString){

      monthName = monthNameToString;

      return monthNameToString;

    }

    public boolean equals(int month) {

        if (Monthnum == month) {
            return true;
        } 
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean greaterThan(int month) {

        if (Monthnum > month) {
            return true;
        } 
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean lessThan(int month) {

        if (Monthnum < month) {
            return true;
        } 
        else {
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You are getting the user input ad integer value.It won't take string values if you use `.nextInt()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to start off, your code will only take in an int due to the use of

```
nextInt();
```

being used (as VVN stated).

```
 int monthNumber = input.nextInt();
```

Your output asks for a month name or number, but your program will only accept a number.

Moving on, the reason that your program defaults to the month January and incorrect number, is because of the way you are handling the error case.

In your setMonthnum() method, you are still setting the Monthnum variable.

```
 if (userMonth < 1 || userMonth > 12){
     System.out.println("Invalid input");
     this.Monthnum = userMonth;
  }
```

So, your program will use whatever incorrect int has been entered and will carry on with execution. The month January is begin displayed as the line of code

```
String monthName = inputMonthNumber.getMonthName(monthNumber);
```

Is going through the switch statement looking for the incorrect number/input. It doesn't find a match, and uses the default case of January.

```
default:
   monthName = "January";
```

If you wanted to fix this, you should add some form of an input trap to prompt the user for another number/input as their previous one was not valid. If you do not wish to prompt for additional input, and simply end execution:

```
System.exit(0);
```

Will stop execution without any errors. However, I would highly suggest adding some form of input trap to manage this. Also, if you want to actually accept month names in the initial input, you may want to use

```
nextLine();
```

over nextInt. This will allow you to take in the line of input as a string. From there, you could determine if the input was a number or a name of the month and act accordingly (parseInt/use month name).

Comment: Yes ,well explained.